# How to parse a Hex word into a filled bit array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I have a Hex byte that I need to convert to binary of 8 bits. This is my current code.

```
if(ID == 65290)
        {
        QBitArray b(Data_0,2);
        QString z=QString::number(Data_0,2);
        if(b.isEmpty())
          {
            ui->Test->setText(z);
            m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
          }
        else
          {
            if(b.testBit(0)==1)
            {
             m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
             ui->Test->setText(z);
            }
          }
```

My issue is when I build the array thus it populates index 0 as the most significant bit. The problem with this is every hex number that starts with a 1 reads as index 0 True. I need to have a filled array that changes with Data_0 hex input that I can bitwise look at the bits. For example:

[0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1] index 0 equals 1
[1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0] index 0 equals 0
etc. The ones are representative of lights on a keypad. Currently 1,2,4,8,16 all show index 0 as 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Data_0 is a hex word fed to this function from an outside source in a CAN network.  b.testBit(0)==1 is working but the index 0 isn't populating as I need it to.

Comment: Please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), without any kind of context and intimate knowledge it's impossible for others to understand them. And with "others" I include *you* in a a year or two (or even just a couple of weeks).

Comment: Joachim. Which numbers are you referring to?

Comment: *All* of them. Try to use named constants in some way, enumerations, `const` or `constexpr` variables, or even preprocessor macros. Will you be able to come back to this code in a couple of years and know the meaning of `418381594` or `65290`?

Comment: Let's see: 65290 (what is significant about this number), 418381594 (What's the meaning of this value), 2 (Why 2, why not 1 or 3?).

Comment: Those numbers are directly related to the network itself so yes they will be understood in the context that framework they are used in is constant. Its a CAN based code so those will make sense to those looking at that code.

Comment: BTW, the common coding guideline is to use hexadecimal notation when dealing with bits.  IMO, bit patterns are easier to see with hexadecimal notation.

Comment: @RyanPensinger:  The idea is that an identifier is easier to read and you can set it in one place and use it multiple times.  If you change the value, only one location needs to be changed.  In your example, you could use `const unsigned int EAT_BREAKFAST_COMMAND = 41838154;` and use the identifier in the two locations.  The code would look like: `sendMsg(EAT_BREAKFAST_COMMAND, `.

Comment: I need to see the Hex notation as a binary so that I can parse the numbers out and look at the individual bits to determine if the light should be active or not. Multiple lights overlap on one Hex byte so I don't want to have a bunch of separate multi dimensional arrays that I have conditions for I just want to look at each bit individually as each is representative of an individual light.

Comment: I also failed to mention I have very little programming experience. I am being tasked to do this for work so explain as though you were speaking to a child and you won't be far off. Ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use strings for that. (And note that "Hexadecimal" is not a value. It is just **a form of notation** of integer values).
Example for you:

```
quint8 a = /* some val */; // your 8-bit value
QBitArray b(8, 0); // bit array
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) // loop by each of 8 bits of your 8-bit value
{
    /* There I create the bitwise mask for
    each bit of your 8-bit value. 
    After that I apply it for the value */

    quint8 theMaskForEachBit = 1 << i; // movement by the order
    bool bit = a & theMaskForEachBit; // appyling the mask 
    b[i] = bit;
}
```

explanation:

```
'<<' is the Bitwise leftshift operator:

1 << 0 is equal to 00000001
1 << 1 is equal to 00000010
...
1 << 7 is equal to 10000000

'&' is the Bitwise AND operator:

01001000 & 
10111000 = 
--------
00001000
```

Good article for understanding bitwise operators in C++: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html
See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Vladimir. Can you explain the code you put down as an answer. Thanks. Also the strings are unrelated I was using that to output something I could see on the display.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Vladimir.